# Splice nested object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, splice

I'm trying to find a simple way to move an object from a nested array and move it to its parent array. I keep getting "splice is not a function," as you can see if you try to use the 'moveItem()' function. I don't know how to re-write this so it works, if it's even allowed to do things this one. Any help is appreciated. In short, I'm trying to move the object from items[0].contains[] to items[] Hope that makes sense.

```js
var items = [{
  itemIndex: 0,
  name: "a box of matches",
  examine: "The box is old and damp,you find a single match inside.",
  location: 0, // if location === 1000, items is in inventory.
  contains: [{
    itemIndex: 1,
    name: "a match",
    examine: "A single match.",
    location: 0,
    contains: [],
    hidden: true,
    collectable: true,
    useWith: 2,
    useWithFail: 0,
    useWithFailResponse: "the box is too damp to light the match",
    useWithSuccessResponse: null
  }], // Contain items inside items using array.
  hidden: false, // if hidden, item cannot show up in invetory or room inventory
  collectable: true,
  useWith: null, // Item that this item can be successfully used with - index or null
  useWithFail: 1, // Use with item that fails but has it's own unique fail message - index or null
  useWithFailResponse: "the box is too damp to light the match",
  useWithSuccessResponse: null
}, {
  itemIndex: 2,
  name: "a closed cupboard",
  examine: "You find a kitchen knife inside",
  location: 4,
  contains: [],
  hidden: false,
  collectable: false,
  useWith: null,
  useWithFail: null,
  useWithFailResponse: null,
  useWithSuccessResponse: "The match spaks into life!"
}, {
  itemIndex: 3,
  name: "a kitchen knife",
  examine: "It is old and rusty.",
  location: 4,
  contains: [],
  hidden: true,
  collectable: true,
  useWith: 1,
  useWithFail: null,
  useWithFailResponse: null,
  useWithSuccessResponse: "The match sparks into life!"
}, ];

function moveItem() {
  items.push(items[0].contains[0].splice(0, 1));
}
```

Comment: contains[0] is not an array, it's an object. you should `contains.splice(0,1)` instead

Comment: Should it not be `items[0].contains.splice(0,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.splice()` returns

> An array containing the deleted elements.

To move a certain object from nested array up to the parent level use the following approach:

```
items.push(items[0].contains.splice(0, 1)[0]);
```